# CheckBoxList selections not being detected

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, checkboxlist

(C# ASP Site) Right now I have a CheckBoxList that is prechecked, depending on what the user selects early in the form. Here's the code to write the prechecks for reference. It works perfectly. Whenever a new prechecking happens cause by user selection => postback

```
        DataTable DefaultActivity = GetData();
        // Resets checkboxes to blank in between postbacks
        for (int p = 0; p < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; p++)
        {
            CheckBoxList1.Items[p].Selected = false;
        }
        // Fills in the prechecked boxes
        if (DefaultActivity.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int SelectedRoleID = Int32.Parse(RadioButtonList2.SelectedValue);
            for (int i = 0; i < DefaultActivity.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                int DatabaseRoleID = Convert.ToInt32(DefaultActivity.Rows[i]["roleid"]);
                if (SelectedRoleID == DatabaseRoleID)
                {
                    int DatabaseActivityID = Convert.ToInt32(DefaultActivity.Rows[i]["activityid"]);
                    for (int j = 0; j < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (DatabaseActivityID == Convert.ToInt32(CheckBoxList1.Items[j].Value))
                        {
                            CheckBoxList1.Items[j].Selected = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem I'm having is that the user should be able to check more boxes in addition to the prechecked boxes, but when they click the Submit Button, it does not detect the newly checked boxes. Here's the Submit Button code.

```
        // Data into the request table
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Server=x;Database=x;User=x;Password=x;Trusted_Connection=False;");
        string Statement = "INSERT INTO table (x) OUTPUT INSERTED.requestid VALUES (x)";
        SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(Statement, sqlConn);

        // Grabs the auto-created RequestID to forward to the next page
        sqlComm.Connection.Open();
        string RequestID = Convert.ToString((Int32)sqlComm.ExecuteScalar());
        sqlComm.Connection.Close();
        sqlComm.Connection.Dispose();

        // Data into the x table
        SqlConnection ActivitysqlConn = new SqlConnection("Server=x;Database=x;User=x;Password=x;Trusted_Connection=False;");
        string ActivityStatement = "INSERT INTO table (x) VALUES (x)";
        for (int k = 0; k < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; k++)
        {
            if (CheckBoxList1.Items[k].Selected == true)
            {
                SqlCommand ActivitysqlComm = new SqlCommand(ActivityStatement, ActivitysqlConn);
                ActivitysqlComm.Connection.Open();
                ActivitysqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                ActivitysqlComm.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect("nextscreen.aspx?RequestID=" + RequestID);
```

Any ideas why the submit button can't see the new checks? It reads the prechecks fine. Side question- is there a more efficient way to Opening/Closing the connections? Be nice, I'm new :)

Comment: Is your code that pre-checks protected in logic (either testing postback, phase in form, some other state machine status) so that you don't overwrite a users selection?  Be mindful that Init, OnLoad, and CreateChildControls will always fire before event handling occurs.

Comment: I currently had the prechecking occur on pageload, which apparently would erase any user changes. You got me thinking about that and now it works perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix- I moved the prechecking code from PageLoad to the RadioButtonList, the object which affects the prechecking. Now all the prechecks and additional checks are properly saved.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your SQL question, this is the "clean" way:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))  
{  
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();  

    command.CommandText = "mysp_GetValue";  
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  

    connection.Open();  
    object ret = command.ExecuteScalar();  
}
```

You should be storing your connection string in configuration somewhere as well as using stored procedures where feasible to help mitigate SQL injection vulnerabilities.

After you answer the comment, we can address your failed check state changes.